# How to get filtered and sorted rows in ag-grid using angular6?

Tags: filter, angular6, ag-grid-angular

I have an ag-Grid with filtering option. How to get the filtered rows  in ag-Grid?

Comment: please suggest me any example or plunker

Comment: Hey Shivakrishna! Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's helpful for other developers to see code examples of the problem you are trying to solve. Also for this specific question, knowing how you are trying to filter your rows is helpful to know.